# What node module i can use to implement clock process on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Here is article about clock node process on heroku: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

However no clock process node module was mentioned there. Does anybody know clock process module for node?